# MYSQL в C#.NET

Tags: c#, база-данных, mysql

Привет всем... вот у меня довольно давно есть сайтик и я решил для познания Баз Данных в C#, сделать админку в виде программы... и так у меня сразу появились вопросы...

- **Как вообще подключатся в БД через программу**
- **Как можно вставить запрос в БД?**
- **Что можно сделать с БД через прогу?**

Если есть книги то скажите автора, пожалуйста, а то такая интересная тема хочется на зубок её знать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В конце сообщения ссылки на туториалы.

Рекомендую Вам разобраться в LinqToSql - после такого на все остальные фреймворки и способы работы с БД "плеваться" потом захочется, всё довольно просто да и работаем не со строкой запроса, а с "сгенерированными" методами для каждой таблицы, которая представляется отдельным классом, создаваемым VS АВТОМАТИЧЕСКИ!!! Плюс - наглядная "карта" нашей базы со всеми связями и т.д.

[Поэтапное руководство работы с MySQL](http://www.functionx.com/mysqlnet/csharp/Lesson01.htm) с сылками на следующие шаги внизу страницы.

[Поэтапное руководство работы с LinqToSql](http://www.tweesta.com/WebAppCodeGod/Tutorial-LINQ-to-SQL---Part-1-AID466.aspx) с сылками на следующие шаги внизу страницы.

Comment: LinqToSql разве работает с MySql? Насколько я знаю, он поддерживает MS SQL Server и MS Sql CE. Впрочем, у Devart есть серия ORM-ов с API, аналогичным Linq2Sql, для разных СУБД, но они платные.

Comment: Я предлагал LinqTo MSSql